# intuitlib.exceptions.AuthClientError: HTTP status 400, error message: b'{"error":"invalid_grant"}'

Tags: oauth-2.0, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online, aws-secrets-manager

Authorization using Oauth 2.0 for the quickbooks service works, access updates and refresh tokens also work (Every 40 minutes).

The problem is that it can work for 2 weeks or 3, but at one point the authorization falls off when the refresh token is updated.

And i got:

```
AuthClientError: HTTP status 400, error message: b'{"error":"invalid_grant"}'
```

To update, I use AWS Lambda and AWS Secret Manager to store tokens.

After authorization flies off, you have to log in with pens, using the generated link, and this is bad when the prod falls in the middle of the night!

I read carefully the articles on Intuit and found an article that says what needs to be checked for such errors.

https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/article/400-Invalid-Grant-invalid-grant

Alas, I didn't find any such flaws in my code.

Actually, maybe someone has faced this kind of problem?